# How to avoid CoffeeScript method variables getting wrapped in object literals?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, scope

CoffeeScript wraps variables declared inside methods in an object literal.

So, this:

```
@Templates =
    get: (templateName) ->
        result: ''              # DECLARED HERE
        $.ajax(
            'Views/Templates/' + templateName + '.html',
            type: 'GET'
            dataType: 'html'
            success: (data) ->
                result = data   # ASSIGNED HERE
            async: false
        )
        return result           # RETURNED HERE
```

Becomes this:

```
(function() {

  this.Templates = {
    get: function(templateName) {
      ({
        result: ''                  //DECLARED IN AN OBJECT LITERAL - I DON'T WANT THIS
      });
      $.ajax('Views/Templates/' + templateName + '.html', {
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
          var result;               //DECLARED LOCAL TO THE CALLBACK - I DON'T WANT THIS
          return result = data;
        },
        async: false
      });
      return result;                //RETURNED HERE - UNASSIGNED
    }
  };

}).call(this);
```

But what I need, and that works for me, is this:

```
(function() {

  this.Templates = {
    get: function(templateName) {
      var result = ''               //DECLARED HERE
      $.ajax('Views/Templates/' + templateName + '.html', {
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
          return result = data;     //ASSIGNED HERE
        },
        async: false
      });
      return result;                //RETURNED HERE
    }
  };

}).call(this);
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: That's not a closure it's an object literal and it's wrapped with parentheses so that it wouldn't be treated as a block

Comment: Synchronous GET? That's probably not a good idea.

Comment: I forgot to mention I am new to CoffeeScript and also Javascript. Thanks all for the answers and tips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've called a closure isn't a closure (closures in JavaScript are always functions). It's an object literal wrapped in parentheses.

I'm not really au fait with CoffeeScript, but if you want `result` to be a local variable in the `get` function, I believe you want to change

```
result: ''
```

to

```
result = ''
```

The former is the object initializer format (hence it getting translated into an object literal), the latter is a variable assignment. Seems to be covered on the CoffeeScript site under [lexical scoping](http://coffeescript.org/#lexical_scope).

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using a `:`? It's not being wrapped in a closure, you are just defining an anonymous object expression.

Just do this:

```
result = ''
```

That said, why are you doing a synchronous GET? That's very frowned upon and will make your site must less responsive.

Answer (score 2):

By `result: ''` you declare a property of an object. What you needed was to declare a local variable by `result = ''`:

```
get: (templateName) ->
    result = ''              # DECLARED HERE
    $.ajax(
        'Views/Templates/' + templateName + '.html',
        type: 'GET'
        dataType: 'html'
        success: (data) ->
            result = data   # ASSIGNED HERE
        async: false
    )
    return result           # RETURNED HERE
```